# Blazor create shared component library

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor

I am trying to work out how to create a shared component library in Blazor.  Basically i want to create my components once and then be able to use them in multiple UI projects.

## Component library

I created a simple component library as follows

```
dotnet new blazorlib -n UsComponentLibrary.Lib
```

Created a component component1.razor

```
<h3>Component1 from lib</h3>

@code {

}
```

## UI

I added a reference to the library in the ui project.  edited the _host.chtml file to include it

```
@page "/"
@namespace UsComponentLibrary.Pages
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@addTagHelper *, UsComponentLibrary.Lib
```

Added it to one of the pages

```
@page "/counter"

hello

<Component1></Component1>

@code {


}
```

## output

The only thing its displaying is Hello i am not getting the text from the component in the library.  What am i missing?  Its like the ui page can see the component but when I run it its not there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to import the namespaces from your library project with `using` statements not the `addTagHelper`. This was a change that came in with Preview 4.

I would suggest you edit the root `_Imports.razor` file in your UI project and add the namespaces there. It should look something like this:

```
@using UsComponentLibrary.Lib
@using UsComponentLibrary.Lib.Components
@using UsComponentLibrary.Lib.WhatEverOtherNameSpaceYouNeed
```

It's also worth noting that the Blazor library project will be depreciated soon and Razor class libraries will be the way to share components for Blazor apps.

Comment: That worked perfectly.   Am i the only one thinking that this should be added automatically when you add the reference?  Maybe i am just asking for to much.

Comment: Blazor library projects are in flux right now so things will definitely improve. Just a heads up static assets from a Blazor library project won't be imported into a Blazor server-side project. Just in-case you try that.

Comment: Okay, Why would you want to load a static asset into a server-sided project?

Comment: If you have shared components that have certain styles or images you may want to include them into whatever project you use the components in. A perfect example of this are nuget packages for UI components such as MatBlazor which is a Blazor version of material design.

Comment: Thats kind of where i am going with this i will probably release it as a nuget package.

Comment: +1 for the last paragraph. For those (like me) looking around for this `blazorlib` template, as of .NET 6 `razorclasslib` is what you want.