# Razor Component Library as Submodule in Blazor/MAUI App Visual Studio 2022 Professional

Tags: c#, .net, maui, git-submodules, razor-component-library

I have a .NET Maui App (.net 6)

I want to add a razor component library which is located in another git repo as a git submodule.

The razor component library has another submodule with a c# class library containing logic an data models.

*Result*: *The submodule inclusion does not behave correctly.*

**What I did:**

A: Create new Project (.NET 6 MAUI)

B: Create new Razor Component Library (.NET 6)

C: Create new c# class library (.NET 4.8 -> it is compatible with .NET 6)

C is submodule of B.

Now Add B as Submodule of A.

**Expectation:**

What I would expect is that I do not see anything in the visual studio project explorer yet.

I usually need to add the projects manually from the file system.

Solution in vs 2022 -> right click -> add existing project

The path is: root of MAUI project -> Submodule B -> .csproj file

Then I would see it in the solution explorer of vs 2022.

Now I can add the submodule as project reference to the .NET Maui project

**What acutally happens:**

After I add Submodule B to the .NET MAUI project via git add submodule "git-repo-url" the Submodule automatically appears in the .NET MAUI project as subfolder.

**Problem:**

If I want to use a component of the submodule in a .razor page in the MAUI app I would need to change all the using directives to the submodules components to MAUI_APP_NAME.SUBMODULE_NAMESPACE.Component which in fact makes the use of submodules useless in the first place.

**Is there anything I did wrong or is it not possible to add razor component libraries as submodules for .NET MAUI apps?**

Any help is appreciated. Thank you all!

Additional Info: This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56839072/blazor-create-shared-component-library) does not describe my problem and not the solution respectively. It only happens when using git-submodules.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this doc: [Reuse Razor components in ASP.NET Core Blazor Hybrid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hybrid/reuse-razor-components?view=aspnetcore-7.0). It involves using Razor Component for .NET MAUI: [.NET MAUI Blazor platform-specific code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hybrid/reuse-razor-components?view=aspnetcore-7.0#net-maui-blazor-platform-specific-code).

In addition, it also provided a .NET MAUI Blazor [sample app](https://github.com/microsoft/dotnet-podcasts). Wish it can help you.

Comment: Thank you for the response.

How I understand the Example:

The razor class library components are located in Podcast.Components which is a project within the project-solution. I cann now use the components e.g. in the Podcast.Pages project by referenceing properly.

This concept is quite clear to me I guess and it works fine.

Comment: But this is not the answer to my problem.

If you have a look at ListenTogetherPage.razor there is a using directive:
@using static Podcast.Components.ListenTogether.ListenTogether

Now I try to emphasize my issue with this again.

If I want to share the components in Podcast.Components as a git submodule with other apps I can't use them properly because I would need to bend the references to the other app's namespace.

Or am I missing s.th. here?

I hope the Issue is a little bit more clarified and s.o. can help :)

Comment: Ok, I got your mean.